# Passing Excel VBA variables to Perl?

Tags: perl, excel, batch-file, multiple-languages, vba

Is it possible to pass variables to a perl script from excel without using Batch as a gateway (VBA -> Batch -> Perl), if not possible how can I send batch variables to Perl?

Comment: I have not worked with perl but a short google search directed me to [This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15698/How-to-execute-a-Perl-script-from-VBA) Not sure if this is what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't pass *variables* to/between *scripts*, but you can pass *values* to/between *processes*.

The number of ways of doing this is nearly infinite. The most common way to pass values from one process to another is through command-line arguments. [This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15698/How-to-execute-a-Perl-script-from-VBA) shows how to execute another program (such as a batch file) from VBA.

What follows is an example of such a batch file passing arguments to a Perl script, which in turn prints them.

```
>type a.bat
@echo off
echo Start of batch file
perl a.pl %*
echo End of batch file
```

```
>type a.pl
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );
say 'Start of Perl script';
say for 0+@ARGV, @ARGV;
say 'End of Perl script';
```

```
>a.bat abc "123 456" def
Start of batch file
Start of Perl script
3
abc
123 456
def
End of Perl script
End of batch file
```

Answer (score 0):

In attached VBA code, i am running a perl script in VBA and passing arguments to it. Perl ARG[0] will have value Kenya and ARGV[1] 2022

```
Sub run_perl()

Dim objShell As Object
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim waitonreturn As Boolean: waitonreturn = True
Dim WindowStyle As Integer: WindowStyle = 0

objShell.Run "E:\perl.pl  Kenya 2022", WindowStyle, waitonreturn

Set objShell = Nothing

End Sub
```